# Bootstrap overriding the default behavior of wordpress

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

I've added bootstrap to my admin page, and that is overridden everywhere. How can I fix that problem?
I've asked it on wordpress.stackexchange.com they suggested me to ask here. I've googled around but i did not get specific answer.
I can't add a screenshot. 
you can visit the screen shot at 
[wordpress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120354/bootstrap-creating-problem-with-wordpress)

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_for_admin_page' );
```

then register and enqueue

Comment: What exactly gets overridden by whom?

Comment: Following the link OP posted, Bootstrap is overriding CSS in his WordPress install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is CSS related.  You are loading Bootstrap's CSS on top of your WordPress Theme, which is overriding other elements and causing unwanted results, which is expected.

Bootstrap's CSS consists of styles for top level DOM elements and thus you are seeing the override issues.  [Bootstrap CSS source](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css)

What you need to figure out is which CSS elements you need from Bootstrap and target them per your WordPress plugin **only**.  Consider the following changes in your BootStrap:

## Bootstrap CSS:

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: inherit;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

## Your Plugin CSS:

```css
#myPlugin h1,
#myPlugin h2,
#myPlugin h3,
#myPlugin h4,
#myPlugin h5,
#myPlugin h6 {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: inherit;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

Also, as another thought.  In your WordPress admin page, instead of:

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_for_admin_page' );
```

You should consider

```php
<?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?> <?php is_plugin_active($plugin) ?>
```

Codex Reference is plugin active: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

As someone else had pointed our in another thread, this really comes down to CSS development and best practices for developing WordPress plugins.